# Google Cloud Message: get RegistrationId from Cordova hybrid app in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

I've just started to develop apps for android.
I've done an Hybrid Cordova app in telerik platform, so I'm using javascript as language.
I need to get push notification sent from a server to my android device.
I have a project in Firebase and I set thecorrect google API Key and ProjectId in my code.
In order to send the message from the server, I need the Registration ID of my app. How could I get?
I found a lot of examples in Java, but none in javascript.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean senderID? Because you will use senderID in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Use cordova push plugin.You can check the reference here [link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push).

Using that plugin you can get registration Id like this :

```
 var push = PushNotification.init({ "android": {"senderID": "YourSenderID"},
    "ios": {"alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true"}, "windows": {} } );

push.on('registration', function(data) {
console.log(data.registrationId);
});
```